# Indexing an R array based on matrix

Tags: r

I am working with relatively large arrays that represent different variables (1000,800,365); the third dimension is time in days. For each row and column, I want to calculate two things based on the maximum of one variable: the sum of another variable and the number of days where the value is less than or equal a given value.

I've used apply() to find the maximum value and its position. I haven't been able to figure out how to calculate my desired variables (have tried various methods of indexing and loops).

Since the data I'm working with is so large, I've been using the following to trouble shoot (x1 is being used as the array with the maximum).

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- array(round(runif(n = 600, min = 0, max = 300)), c(5,10,12))
x2 <- array(round(runif(n = 600, min = 0, max = 200)), c(5,10,12))
x1.max <- apply(x1, c(1,2), max)
x1.max.pos <- apply(x1, c(1,2), which.max)
```

Ultimately, I want to have two 1000x800 matrices (one with the sum of x2 after x2.max and the other with the number of occurrences equal to a value after x2.max) once everything is all said and done.

Edited to add:
Here's some additional clarification about what I'm looking for

```
> x1.max.pos <- apply(x1, c(1,2), which.max)
> x1.max <- apply(x1, c(1,2), max)
x1.max.pos
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10    7    9   10    3    7    7    9    7     2
[2,]    6    1    4    1   10    2   12    8   11    11
[3,]    9   10    7    1    8    9    4    8    6     9
[4,]    3    3    5    7    7   11    8    3    4    10
[5,]    8    9   12   12    5   11    3    7   12     5
> x2[1,1,]
 [1] 163 135 186  99 172 189 166  19 106   9 138 168
> sum(x2[1,1,10:12])
[1] 315
> x2[2,1,]
 [1] 186 169 180 180   7 149 153  36 137 107  51  16
> sum(x2[2,1,6:12])
[1] 649
```

At at x2[1,1,], I want to find the sum of the values after the number identified in x1.max.pos[1,1]. My final matrix should have the value of 315 for the first row and first column, and 649 for the second row and first column.

From there, I ultimately need to know the number of times for each row and column the value is greater than 0 (with the sample matrices I know it won't work quite right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

With the update it became clear what the OP really wanted. Here's a solution to this problem:

```r
res <- vapply(seq_along(x1.max.pos), 
       function(i) {
          sum(x2[row(x1.max.pos)[i], 
                 col(x1.max.pos)[i], 
                 seq(x1.max.pos[i], dim(x1)[3])])
       }, 
       double(1L)
)

dim(res) <- dim(x1.max.pos)
res
```

The idea is rather straight forward: loop through all max positions, take the corresponding slice from `x2` and sum it. Since the dimension is lost in this loop we have to re-assign it.

### Old answer

<s>I do not fully understand your expected outcome, but I guess `sweep` can help:</s>

```r
apply(sweep(x2, 1:2, x1.max, function(x, s) {
 res <- x - s
 res[res < 0] <- 0
res}), 1:2, sum)
```

The idea is that you provide a summary stat (e.g. `x1.max`) and a function which operates on the data and this summary stat. his function takes the respective slot of your data and the summary stat and does whatever you tell it to do.

Here I simply substract the maximum, and set negative values (i.e. values which are smaller than the maximum) to zero (pretty useless, but just to highlight the idea). Then you need one more run to apply to aggregate the data.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the original question to provide additional context.

Comment: Ok, now your problem became clear. I updated my answer.